# Excel Macro to copy x numbers of rows separately

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a excel Macro that allows to me copy an x number of rows of certain column. For Example, I have column K that I have in 10.500 rows. I want to copy 1000 lines each time and also the 500 lines at the end. any help with the coding part ? I looked on so many sites and no success. I don't need to paste the copied number in any other excel sheet. I just need the macro command to copy me 1000 lines every time from the column that I selected.
thank youuuuu very much and much appreciated ! 
Cheers

Comment: I'm struggling with the fact that apparently you have *'looked on so many sites'* and have absolutely nothing to show for it.

Comment: Do you want to copy the data to... a new sheet?  A new workbook?  1000 new rows at the bottom of your table?  Microsoft Word?  Somewhere else?

Comment: @elliotsvensson I want to paste the 1000 lines copied into Cognos and not another sheet that's why I didn't mention that. I need a command that just copies a 1000 lines at each time because Cognos only takes 1000 lines of data at everytime. Thank you for your reply !

Comment: @Jeeped I kinda didn't get what you are saying..I looked around and didn't find any solution to what I want to do..

Answer (score 1):

1. Select a column and run the sub procedure from the Macros dialog (Alt+F8). The first 1000 cells will be copied to the clipboard.
2. Paste the data into another program.
3. Return to Excel and run the sub procedure again. The next 1000 rows of data will be copied to the clipboard.
4. When the last group of data has been copied to the clipboard, a message box will notify.

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Sub progressiveCopy()
       Dim m As Long
       Static i As Long, k As Long

       Application.CutCopyMode = False
       m = 1000

       If k <> ActiveCell.Column Then
           k = ActiveCell.Column
           i = 0
       End If

       With Worksheets("sheet1")
           m = Application.Min(m, .Cells(.Rows.Count, k).End(xlUp).Row - i)
           .Cells(i + 1, k).Resize(m, 1).Copy
           i = i + m
           If i >= .Cells(.Rows.Count, k).End(xlUp).Row Then
               MsgBox "This column is complete. Select another column next time."
           End If
       End With
   End Sub
   ```

You may wish to set up a hot-key combination for the sub procedure in the Macros dialog to ease repetitive operations.

Comment: It worked !! Thank you very much ! Much appreciated ! Not All Heroes wear Caps ! You are a Star !!

Answer (score 0):

This code finds the number of rows in the currently selected column.  Checks if the number to be copied is less than the rows left.  Selects the range and puts the range in copy mode.  After the range is copied you would have to go to they sheet, document, or whatever to paste the data.

I've modified the code to then select down 1000 rows or what ever is left in the column.  So you should be able to run the code, paste the data, run the code, paste the data.  When you hit the end, a message tells you that you are at the end of the column.

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
numRowstoCopy = 1000
varCurrentRow = ActiveCell.Row
varCurrentColumn = ActiveCell.Column
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, varCurrentColumn).End(xlUp).Row
varRowsToEnd = FinalRow - varCurrentRow
If varRowsToEnd < numRowstoCopy Then
    Range(Cells(varCurrentRow, varCurrentColumn), Cells(varCurrentRow + varRowsToEnd, varCurrentColumn)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    MsgBox "Last Rows to Paste Have been copied"
Else
    Range(Cells(varCurrentRow, varCurrentColumn), Cells(varCurrentRow + numRowstoCopy - 1, varCurrentColumn)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(numRowstoCopy, 0).Select
End If
```

Comment: So If I understood this correctly, This code will copy the first 1000 lines of the selected column and after I paste the selected data, if I go back to the file, will it copy the next 1000 lines ? Thank you very much for your answer ! it is really helpful !

Comment: I've edited the code slightly based on a better understanding of what you trying to do.